# Drupal 7 iframe with .html file located inside theme

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7

I have a theme which contains a folder called "user_news". The folder is in my_theme/user_news. And inside that folder I have an index.html file which I want to load in an iframe on my Drupal 7 site.

I tried this:

```
<iframe src="<?=variable_get("portal_link", NULL);?>/my_theme/user_news/index.html" width="600px" heigh="500px"></iframe>
```

The iframe is placed on the front page of my site. But it always shows a 404 page.

Any ideas what might be causing this. 
And even when I copy the full link and place it in the url bar in the browser, it shows a 404 (i.e: https://portal_link/my_theme/user_news/index.html).
When I do the same with a css file for example (https://portal_link/my_theme/user_news/css/main.css) it loads perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a new .htaccess file in the target folder, eg folder1/.htaccess
Add the lines

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +Indexes
```

Now index.htm and .html files may be served from there.

If this does not work, try to add an exception to this folder in Drupals .htaccess file. Check it here: https://www.drupal.org/node/30334

Answer (score 0):

You cant access any index.html directly from the theme in your browser. You need to create a menu for that. Css files can be loaded directly because they are excluded in the htaccess file.

Comment: I am relatively new to Drupal. How would I go about creating a menu for that?

Comment: what is your requirement. You want a new url or you want to display the iframe in any node or block

Comment: I want to display the iframe in any block or any custom template page on my site

Comment: You can just create a block and in the body just add an iframe tag and select full html in the text format field.